# Quicksort: Infinite Loop

Tags: python, sorting, infinite-loop, quicksort

The following implementation of `QuickSort` runs into infinite loop

```py
def partition(arr, lo, hi):
    pivot = lo
    for i in range(lo+1, hi+1):
        if arr[i] <= arr[lo]:
            pivot += 1
            arr[i], arr[pivot] = arr[pivot], arr[i]
    arr[lo], arr[pivot] = arr[pivot], arr[lo]
    return pivot

def quickSort(arr, lo=0, hi=None):
    if not hi: hi = len(arr) - 1
    if lo >= hi: return

    pivot = partition(arr, lo, hi)
    quickSort(arr, lo, pivot-1)
    quickSort(arr, pivot+1, hi)


arr = [5,3,2,-9,1,6,0,-1,9,6,2,5]
quickSort(arr)
print(arr)
```

I presume the `partition` function is the culprit. Not able to figure out the mistake.

Thanks

Comment: You're calling `quicksort()` from within `quicksort()` without implementing some sort of way to stop infinite recursion.

Comment: He has this end condition already in place.

Comment: please mark answer as correct, if you found it useful.

Comment: `if lo >= hi: return`

Comment: @prabodhprakash OP will probably mark as "correct" the answer that points out the flaw in their implementation.

Comment: @this-vidor In my opinion, it should be before the swap. On first iteration we do not wish to swap the `arr[lo]` with `arr[i]`.

Comment: @ShubhamChandel Yes, you are correct. Have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your initialization code for `hi`:

```
if not hi: hi = len(arr) - 1
```

The condition `not hi` is `True` if `hi` is zero.

This causes `quicksort(arr, 0, 0)` and `quicksort(arr, 1, 0)` (one of which will almost always occur in the process of sorting) to try to sort most of the list again, rather than being an end to the recursion.

You should use the more specific test `if hi is None` instead of `if not hi`. This way you'll never incorrect reinitialize `hi` if it's zero, and the initialization code will only run if `hi` is `None` because it was not passed in to the function by the user.

Comment: That nifty little detail I missed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

At one point, your loop never works in partition def. See below

```
[5, 3, 2, -9, 1, 6, 0, -1, 9, 6, 2, 5]
lo 0 hi 11
pivot 8
[5, 3, 2, -9, 1, 0, -1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 9]
lo 0 hi 7
pivot 7
[2, 3, 2, -9, 1, 0, -1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
lo 0 hi 6
pivot 5
[-1, 2, -9, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
lo 0 hi 4
pivot 1
[-9, -1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
lo 0 hi 11
pivot 0
[-9, -1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
lo 1 hi 11
```

partition doesn't seem to be doing the entire job and correctly, it is a two step process. See a sample partition def below. Also, you can refer to original source [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html):

```
 def partition(alist,first,last):
   pivotvalue = alist[first]

   leftmark = first+1
   rightmark = last

   done = False
   while not done:

       while leftmark <= rightmark and alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1

       if rightmark < leftmark:
           done = True
       else:
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp

   temp = alist[first]
   alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
   alist[rightmark] = temp


   return rightmark
```

Comment: I have implemented this kind of two cross-pointer partition, it works fine. But I'm unable to figure out the mistake in my partition function.

Comment: At one of the intermediate steps of partition, your array looks like ``[-9, -1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]`` and then it goes into infinite  loop